# Как сделать разметку для страницы на android ?

Tags: android, java

Как сделать разметку для страницы на android на подобии этого примера:

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Comment: посмотри видео[link text][1]


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eZFNkXAF1WM&index=18&list=PLIU76b8Cjem7oSU18zTKNfsyzrmf3Zubl

Answer (score 1):

Такую разметку делать довольно просто, конечно разметка делается только для одного элемента и используется потом в кастомном ArrayAdapter.
Для начала вам нужно описать контейнер LinearLayout с ориентацией horizontal и разделить его двумя элементами ImageView с layout_weight 1 и еще один контейнер LinearLayout с layout_weight 2, но на этот раз с ориентацией vertical. В этом контейнере размещаете два TextView и еще один контейнер очень похожий на первый.

Comment: За**ься такое делать на `ArrayAdapter` :)

Comment: Почему? Какое решение, предлагаете вы?